# Javascript async await does not work in if-statement

Tags: javascript, async-await

I cannot figure out why the following Javascript async await is not working.

```
async function fetchDataAndComputeSomething (ids) {
  let response
  if (ids && ids.length > 0) {
    // ids specified, fetch some data with same ids from service.
    response = await fetchDataWrapper (ids)
    console.log('IfBlockResponse = ' + JSON.stringify(response, null, 4))
    // do something specific with response data here.
  } else {
    // ids not specified, use null to get all data from service.
    response = await fetchDataWrapper (null)
    console.log('ElseBlockResponse = ' + JSON.stringify(response, null, 4))
    // do something different with response data here.
  }
}

async function fetchDataWrapper (ids) {
  let dicToReturn = {}

  const responseData = await actualFetchDataMethod(ids)
  for (let i = 0; i < responseData.length; i++) {
    let responseItem= responseData[i]
    dicToReturn [responseItem.id] = responseItem
  }
  return dicToReturn 
}
```

but, this is ok.

```
async function fetchDataAndComputeSomething (ids) {
  let response
  if (ids && ids.length > 0) {
    // ids specified, fetch some data with same ids from service.
    response = await fetchDataWrapper (ids)
  } else {
    // ids not specified, use null to get all data from service.
    response = await fetchDataWrapper (null)
  }

  console.log('Response = ' + JSON.stringify(response, null, 4))
  if (something) {
    // do something specific with response data here.
  } else {
    // do something different with response data here.
  }
}

async function fetchDataWrapper (ids) {
  let dicToReturn = {}

  const responseData = await actualFetchDataMethod(ids)
  for (let i = 0; i < responseData.length; i++) {
    let responseItem= responseData[i]
    dicToReturn [responseItem.id] = responseItem
  }

  return dicToReturn 
}
```

The fist example, the response is a dictionary of my expected keys, but, values are null.
The second example the response is a dictionary of my expected keys and expected values.

Somehow, when the code is in the same if-block, it gets incorrect value. But, if I put code outside the if-block, it will wait on the actual data. As you can see, I have to duplicate the if-condition, so, the logic can be ran outside the if-block that contains the await. I can do this as workaround, but, I don't know exactly why the first example doesn't work.

Comment: Can you show us your real code "if (something)"?

Comment: Are you by chance using a transpiler, like `Babel`? If not, what browser or platform is this running on? Also, any way you can create [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @Renato Coqueiro, I updated the code

Comment: I am running on Google Chrome 80.0.3987.132. I am not sure if Babel is used or not because someone already setup the system, I am only to modify it. Maybe it is a Babel limitation?

Comment: What's the intention with the recursion in `fetchData`?

Comment: @Bryan Downing you mean the for-loop that translate a list of json objects into a dictionary with id as key?

Comment: No, I mean you have a function called fetchData that immediately calls fetchData: `const responseData = await fetchData(ids)`

Comment: oh sorry, i was manually editing, my bad. Going to fix it.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't spend more time on verifying the cause of the problems yet. It could just be Babel limitation. Also, I have to use Babel either way. I just use the workaround in my original post. Simply put the code after await outside the if-statement is good enough for me.